# How to prevent certain Facebook friends from sending you Inbox messages

Tags: facebook, privacy, security

Is there a way to prevent a Facebook friend from sending you Inbox messages?  I want to have a group called "Public Contact Only" that basically cannot have side-bar conversations with me.  The idea is that if they want to communicate with me, I'll want it to be "Facebook public" (wall posts) only.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Facebook Page.  That sounds exactly like what you want. http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=904

Comment: Agreed; you cannot prevent friends from sending you Inbox messages.

Comment: Plus, with a page, people can be your "fan". Everyone needs fans :-)